# Best practice to pass a very long string trough WebAPI to another WebAPI Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

im fairly new to ASP.Net programming.

I have the following question.

I have two WebAPI Projects on two different servers. One API collects some data from different XML files. The other API has the only task to look if a file exists on the server. So the first API collects the data, sends a string with the file and path name to the other API, wait for an answer and put this answer to the collected data.

```
[
    {"Id":12858,"Name":"Foo","Depth":5,"ParentId":12818,"ClipId":-1,"Clips":[here comes the result]},
    {"HierarchyId":12929,"Name":"Bar","Depth":5,"ParentId":12818,"ClipId":-1,"Clips":[here comes the result]}, ... 
]
```

My first approach was to make an request for every file. So it can be normal that 50 requests had to be taken before the data collection was finished. That works really fine, but very slow too. It takes much time waiting for the response for thes 50 linear requests.

The idea is to send an long string, an array or a list that contains all strings with the path and the filename. E.g. C:\foo.txt;C:\bar.txt;....
With a GET Request the url ist far too long.

Which is a good practice to solve this? I try several hours different solutions with POST requests. But i don't think that this is THE solution. A deep research on some search machines given no good answer too. I'm sure there must be an easy solution for this.

Comment: How large of a string are we talking about?  Send it via JSON.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but don't send the data until you are sure the server needs to receive it. It may be cheaper to make one 'exists' request passing the file meta-data per item, and based on the answer to the 'exists' request make a separate 'post' request that actually contains the file data.

Comment: The string for one File is 80 chars long. I have the posibility to shrink the length to +-30. But i think this solution will not future proof because it is possible that the amount of files will increase. Try to end it via raw and via json.